# Ngrok doesn't start tunnel when running docker engine

Tags: docker, ngrok, tunnel

I have this docker container running on port 5000:5000 using the command `docker run --name api -p 5000:5000 luigigabriel/api-nova1.0:push4` then I have the ngrok extension installed at my vscode app. However, every time I try`>ngrok:start` and set port to 5000 (as my server), it gives me this error: `There was an error starting your tunnel`. Please, if someone knows how to fix it, let me know.

I've tried to install ngrok and also to pull the docker image once again. But, when I run the docker container, using the server adress correctly on the browser, I can acess the routes, but can't create a tunner using ngrok in vscode.

Also, I tried to install ngrok directly on Windows, but it gives me an error in ngrol.yml file.

Comment: Using https://pinggy.io you can use this command `ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:5000 a.pinggy.io`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the open source project Tunnelmole (https://github.com/robbie-cahill/tunnelmole-client). Once installed you should be able to expose your docker container with `tmole 5000`.